# Doesn't shut down.

Tags: shutdown

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 in my Lenovo laptop. 
Every time I turn off the PC , a stream of data appears on a back screen showing "printk messages dropped" and "SCHED_ERROR" and the system doesn't shut down even after a long time. I'll have to shut down by long pressing power button only. 
Please help me out.

Comment: Do your laptop have an Nvidia graphic card?

Comment: Yes it has Nvidia GeForce 920MX graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this issue with my new **Lenovo Ideapad 320**.

**I changed the "grub configuration" to solve it**

Please Try this solution.

Open your terminal by CTRL+ALT+T

Open "grub configuration" file by typing

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

Find the following line from the file just opened.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

change the above line to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

save your changes.

Now update your grub configuration by issuing this command

sudo update-grub

Now reboot the system.

It solved my booting and shutdown problems,hope it may help.

Comment: Thanks Vishnu S Vyshakh!. I also had this problem with a new Lenovo Ideapad L340 and ubuntu 18.04. 
But NOW I can not use the screen bright control buttons. Is at its brightest possibility and cant i can't turn down the monitor brightness!

Answer (score 0):

I tried Vishnu solution and worked... but NOW I can not use the screen bright control buttons. Is at its brightest possibility and cant i can't turn down the monitor brightness!
Does anyone know any possible solution?
Thanks
Lenovo Ideapad L340 Ubuntu 18.04.44